# Run Javascript from Obj-C/C++ that interacts with Photoshop

Tags: javascript, c++, objective-c, photoshop

Slightly related to my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672984/get-photoshops-action-list-using-objective-c), how do I execute JavaScript from an Obj-C/C++ program on OSX? (I think JavaScript will allow me to do what I need to, even though AppleScript doesn't. According to the Photoshop documentation anyway.)

I need it to be able to interact with Photoshop.

Answer (score 0):

While I really doubt using Javascript will allow you to do what you want (how is Javascript going to achieve what you need if AppleScript can't?), if you're looking to execute Javascript from Cocoa, `WebKit` is probably your only option. Take a look at [this](http://www.thimbleby.net/script/) tutorial, and see it will provide you with the tools you need.

Comment: The Photoshop scripting documentation actually explicitly states that they support VBS, JavaScript, and AppleScript. But the Action Manager API (the only one I really NEED :P) says that it is not supported in AppleScript, but it doesn't say why...